# Same xml load on multiple button click in Android

Tags: android, xml

I have multiple button in Main Activity, and on every button click same xml is loaded like "test.xml" with dynamic data. The "test.xml" which I loaded on every click contain five more buttons and for every click of "test.xml" buttons I again want to load same xml,i.e, "test.xml" with different data. How I acheive this task.

main.xml is-

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/idc_leftLayout"

    >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/idc_game1"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/g1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:onClick="stratGame1"
     />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/idc_game2"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/g2" 
    android:layout_below="@id/idc_game1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:onClick="stratGame2"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/idc_game3"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/g3"
    android:layout_below="@id/idc_game2"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
    android:onClick="stratGame3"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/idc_game4"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/g4"
    android:layout_below="@id/idc_game3"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:onClick="stratGame4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/idc_game5"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/g5"
    android:layout_below="@id/idc_game4"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:onClick="stratGame5" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

test.xml is

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/idc_questionOption1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/idc_questionOption2"
    android:background="@drawable/lev1ques1img3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/idc_questionOption2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/idc_questionOption3"
    android:background="@drawable/lev1ques1img4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/idc_questionOption3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="79dp"
    android:background="@drawable/lev1ques1img5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/idc_question"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/idc_questionOption1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/lev1ques1img2" />
```

Please help me for the same.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I edited my post, please help me for same.

Answer (score 0):

You should use multiple activities

**Main Activity**

```
...
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button_1_id);
Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button_2_id);
...
button1.setOnClickListener(this);
button2.setOnClickListener(this);
...
public void onCLick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.your_button_1_id) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("calledFromButton", 1);
        startActivity(i,1);
    } else if(v.getId() == R.id.your_button_2_id) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("calledFromButton", 2);
        startActivity(i,1);
    }
    ...
}
...
```

**Test Activity**

```
...
int calledFromButton = getIntent().getIntExtra("calledFromButton");
...
```

Now you have in the variable calledFromButton the number from the button, that you clicked.

Comment: I don't want to use Multiple Activities because same scenario is processed multiple times, so I want to implement same activity but change data at run time.

Comment: You could use `setContentView(test1.xml)` in the OnClickListener, but then you need different layouts for different Buttonclicks.